# Can the environment for Amazon Batch be a Windows OS?

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services

Developers,

I would like to use AWS Batch to run tasks on a Windows OS.  Literature states that the work is done in a Linux Container.

Can only a Linux based EC2 be used in Amazon Batch?

Thanks,
Marc

Comment: Batch runs the job for you.  The job is a docker container.  If you can put Windows in the Docker container (and you can) then it'll run.  I'm not following you in terms of asking about EC2 also.

Comment: Please note [tag:batch-file] does not mean Amazon batch.

Comment: 1) I would assume that a Windows exe would not run in a Linux Docker container and 2) I can not run from AWS Batch a WIndows Docker container.  Statement 1 is based on a Docker container shares the OS and statement 2 is from the AWS Batch UI.

Answer (score 0):

AWS Batch can't run windows exe's.